Problem when trying to bridge multiple topics using ros-gzharmonic-bridge from launch file
Environment:

OS: Ubuntu 22.04
ROS version: humble
Gazebo version: 8.2.0 (harmonic)
ros_gzharmonic_bridge version: 0.244.12-3jammy

Launch file:
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.conditions import IfCondition
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration,PathJoinSubstitution

from launch_ros.actions import Node


def generate_launch_description():

    pkg_ros_gz_sim = get_package_share_directory('ros_gz_sim')
    uuv=get_package_share_directory('uuv')

    gz_sim = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
            os.path.join(pkg_ros_gz_sim, 'launch', 'gz_sim.launch.py')),
        launch_arguments={'gz_args': PathJoinSubstitution([
            uuv,
            'worlds',
            'buoyant_lrauv.sdf'
        ])}.items(),
    )

    # Bridge
    bridge = Node(
        package='ros_gz_bridge',
        executable='parameter_bridge',
        arguments=['/model/my_lrauv/joint/propeller_joint/cmd_thrust@std_msgs/msg/Float64@gz.msgs.Double',
                   '/model/my_lrauv/joint/vertical_fins_joint/0/cmd_pos@std_msgs/msg/Float64@gz.msgs.Double'],
        output='screen'
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        gz_sim,
        bridge,
    ])

Terminal output:
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/madhup/.ros/log/2024-05-07-17-46-05-014018-madhup-Legion-Slim-7-16IRH8-13076
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [ruby $(which gz) sim-1]: process started with pid [13077]
[INFO] [parameter_bridge-2]: process started with pid [13080]
[parameter_bridge-2] [INFO] [1715084165.071189838] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/model/my_lrauv/joint/propeller_joint/cmd_thrust (gz.msgs.Double) -> /model/my_lrauv/joint/propeller_joint/cmd_thrust (std_msgs/msg/Float64)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-2] [INFO] [1715084165.071713447] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating ROS->GZ Bridge: [/model/my_lrauv/joint/propeller_joint/cmd_thrust (std_msgs/msg/Float64) -> /model/my_lrauv/joint/propeller_joint/cmd_thrust (gz.msgs.Double)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-2] [INFO] [1715084165.071909710] [ros_gz_bridge]: Creating GZ->ROS Bridge: [/model/my_lrauv/joint/vertical_fins_joint/0/cmd_pos (gz.msgs.Double) -> /model/my_lrauv/joint/vertical_fins_joint/0/cmd_pos (std_msgs/msg/Float64)] (Lazy 0)
[parameter_bridge-2] [WARN] [1715084165.071985040] [ros_gz_bridge]: Failed to create a bridge for topic [/model/my_lrauv/joint/vertical_fins_joint/0/cmd_pos] with ROS2 type [std_msgs/msg/Float64] to topic [/model/my_lrauv/joint/vertical_fins_joint/0/cmd_pos] with Gazebo Transport type [gz.msgs.Double]


Ever got to a solution on this? I'm having the same issue...
